I'm using React-Router-Dom for page routes and <Outlet /> for navigation. However, it's not working as expected
I've incorporated the Outlet component into my setup to ensure seamless navigation with the Navigation across all pages. However, despite the implementation, it's failing to display as expected on each page.
App.js
import { createBrowserRouter,RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./Pages/home";
import Contact from './Pages/contact';
import AboutPage from "./Pages/About";
import RootLayout from "./Pages/Root";
import ProductPage from "./Pages/Product";
import ProductDetails from "./Pages/ProductDetails";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
      path: '/',
      elements: <RootLayout />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: [
        {path:'/', element:<HomePage />},
          { path: 'contact', element: <Contact /> },
          { path: 'about', element: <AboutPage /> },
          { path: 'product', element: <ProductPage /> },
          { path: 'product/:productId', element: <ProductDetails /> },
      ],
  },
]);


function App() {
  return (
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}

export default App;

Route.js
import {Outlet} from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "../components/navigation";

const RootLayout=()=>{
    return (
        <>
       <Navigation />
       <Outlet />
       </>
    )
}
export default RootLayout;

Navigation.js
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
const Navigation=()=>{
    return (
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><NavLink to='/' className={({isActive})=>
            isActive? 'active': undefined
                    }
                    end
                    >Home</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li><NavLink to='/contact' className={(isActive)=>
                        isActive?'active':undefined
                    }
                    end
                    >
                    Contact</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li><NavLink to='/about'>About</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Navigation;

Navigation was supposed to appear in every page but it is not appearing in any page.
I am using Outlet which is a part of React-Router-Dom library It was suppose to show the navbar in every page.

element: <RootLayout /> instead of elements: <RootLayout />

elements is invalid. Use element instead. See below for the updated code:
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <RootLayout />, // Fixed from 'elements' to 'element'
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      { path: '/', element: <HomePage /> },
      { path: 'contact', element: <Contact /> },
      { path: 'about', element: <AboutPage /> },
      { path: 'product', element: <ProductPage /> },
      { path: 'product/:productId', element: <ProductDetails /> },
    ],
  },
]);

